# Posting to Web API in code returns “Not Authorized”

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I’m trying to post to a Web API that is using Basic Authentication. When I POST using Fiddler I’m able to post the data successfully. Now I’m trying to do the same in a C# console App but I continue to get a 401 Unauthorized response.

When I run the code through Debug I can seed the credentials are getting Base64 encoded properly. Doing some research online I believe I have the correct code. Anyone see if I’m missing anything?

```
if (lstEmployee != null && lstEmployee.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://website.com/api/employees/upload";);


            //set credentials and add them to the client header
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));     
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);


            //set to use JSON
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            foreach (var employee in lstEmployee)
            {
                //Convert to JSON with Newtonsoft
                string employeeJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);


                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(fullServiceURL, employeeJSON).Result;


                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //If successfull, do something. 

                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Error("Error posting to Web API. Employee: {0} | {1} ({2})", employee.EmployeeNumber, (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error("Error posting to Web API. | {0} | Trace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
else
{
    logger.Info("No records found.");
}
```

In Fiddler I just added the following to the Header in the composer tab along with some JSON data in the body and it worked.

```
Authorization: Basic abChaXJ3YXlzLmludGVncmF0aW9uOnRlc3Q0ZGNhYTIwMTU=
Host: services.website.com
Content-Length: 374
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

**  UPDATE  **

I tweaked the code to the following. Now I get an error Status 400 "Bad Request". It looks like it's complaining about being malformed data. However, I logged the JSON list value and added it to the body of Fiddler. I can post the captured JSON in Fiddler just fine. I don't know what else to check to see what's malformed about it.

Here is the results of my JSON list after going through Newtonsoft. I'm only pulling one record for testing purposes

```
[{"EmployeeNumber":"22449","CompanyHireDate":"2014-12-15T00:00:00","Username":"EN022449","LastName":"AVIVA","FirstName":"JOE","MiddleInitial":null,"BirthDate":"1967-10-06T00:00:00","PhoneNumber":null,"EmailAddress":"EN999-Joe.Aviva@company.com","Location":"BOS","Address1":null,"Address2":null,"City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"OverrideSeniorityOrder":0}]
```

Here is my updated code:

```
if (lstEmployee != null && lstEmployee.Count > 0)
{
    logger.Info("Employee count: " + lstEmployee.Count);

    string baseUrl = "https://services.website.com/api/";
    string serviceUrl = "employees/upload";

    string fullServiceURL = baseUrl + serviceUrl;
    logger.Debug("Web API Uri: " + fullServiceURL);

    try
    {
        //Convert the list to JSON
        string employeeJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstEmployee);
        logger.Debug("employeeJSON: " + employeeJSON);

        //Add credentials to Client Handler
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {   
            //set URI and to use JSON
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(fullServiceURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(fullServiceURL, employeeJSON).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //success
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Error("Error posting to Web API. {0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error("Error posting to Web API. | {0} | Trace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
else
{
    logger.Info("No records found.");
}
```

Comment: Right after setting the authorization header, you do this: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();`  Might pay to reorder the operations.

Comment: Thanks. That got me closer. I should have seen that as well but after looking it over and over again I missed that. I'm getting a different error but at least it's not an Unauthorized.

Comment: What is the new error?  Update your question with the pertinent details.

Comment: I get a status 400 now which looks to be malformed data. I wrote out the data of my employeeJSON object after it goes through Newtonsoft and it looks like it's missing the [] around the data. I'm guessing I need to put the object in a List and then send that over.

Comment: Question updated to see if anyone has any suggestions on what might be causing my Status 400.

Comment: It might be worthwhile adding the code for the WebAPI POST action that you are sending the data to.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the code where I'm sending the data to. It's a 3rd party service.

Comment: The post is supposed return an array of objects letting me know which if the insert of each employee was successful or not. Not sure if that's part of the problem since I can send this post through Fiddler just fine.

Comment: Answer to my last issue in case it helps someone else. Looks like using client.PostAsJsonAsync will automatically serialize the object into JSON for you. Since I was using Newtonsoft to serialize my list and then used PostAsJsonAsync it was effectively serializing the list twice and thus causing the Status 400 of malformed data. Letting the PostAsJsonAsync take care of the serializing for me seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The HttpClientHandler, introduced in .Net 4.5 saves you from having to encode the authentication headers by hand. Use it like this:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
using (var http = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that snippet. Is the default Basic Authentication? Or, do I need to specific to use Basic?

Comment: I would assume that it negotiates with the server. But if you know that you are going to use basic authentication you can set PreAuthenticate=true on the HttpClientHandler. This will add the authentication headers immediately, and skip the challenge/response roundtrip to the server.